# How to compare only the column names of 2 data frames using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have 2 Data Frames with matched and unmatched column names, I want to compare the column names of the both the frames and print a table/dataframe with unmatched column names.
Please someone help me on this

I have no idea how can i achieve this

Below is the expectation

[DF1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvwCX.png)

[DF2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6pfw.png)

Output:
[Output should actual vs unmatched column name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7G4H.png)

Comment: Please add same dataframes and what you've tried

Comment: Do you want to compare just the names of column or column values?

Comment: @RonakJain Only column names

Comment: Added my answer, let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
As per Expected output in Questions. The requirement is to compare both dataframes with similar schema but different names and make a dataframe of mismatched column names.

Thus, my best bet would be:

```
df3 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(idx,x) for idx,x in enumerate(df1.schema.names) if x not in df2.schema.names]).toDF("#","Uncommon Columns From DF1")\
.join(spark.createDataFrame([Row(idx,x) for idx, x in enumerate(df2.schema.names) if x not in df1.schema.names]).toDF("#","Uncommon Columns From DF2"),"#")
```

**The catch here is, the schema should be similar as it compares column names based on "ordinals" i.e. their respective positions in the schema.**

Input/Output

[image: Input/Output]

Change the join type to "full_outer" in case there are extra columns in either dataframe.

```
df3 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(idx,x) for idx,x in enumerate(df1.schema.names) if x not in df2.schema.names]).toDF("#","Uncommon Columns From DF1").join(spark.createDataFrame([Row(idx,x) for idx, x in enumerate(df2.schema.names) if x not in df1.schema.names]).toDF("#","Uncommon Columns From DF2"),"#", "full_outer")
```

Input/Output
[image: Input/Output]

Comment: The above code is comparing the column names and printing non matched column names, I want to show the actual name from DF1 W.R.T non matched name in DF2 in separate Dataframe

Comment: @Nareshreddy Didn't get you? As per your earlier comment, you want only Columns Names to be compared - not values. Here It's comparing Columns from DF1 and Columns from DF2 and creating a new dataframe with those name. Can you update your question with Sample output, it would help?

Comment: @Nareshreddy Do you only want unmatched columns from DF1 i.e. the above result will have Address and Phone only?

Comment: Yes just want to compare column names from the both the Dataframes and want to print the actual name from DF1 W.R.T non matched name in DF2 in separate Dataframe

Comment: @Nareshreddy Updated the answer, added your requirement as per comments as well.

Comment: Just updated the description with expected output with images, please look into this and help me

Comment: @Nareshreddy I still didn't get it, both your dataframes are exactly identical and output is even more confusing - if both dataframes are equal how the values populated in your output?

Comment: The column names are different in both the dataframes, DF1 has firstname and DF2 has first_name.

Comment: @Nareshreddy Updated, let me know if you need any help

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is working as expected if we have same count of columns in the both the Dataframes, It could be helpful if you assist me to get extra columns in df2. I mean df1 have 5 columns and df2 have 7 columns, i want to print extra columns in df2 and null in df1

Comment: I want to merge this request to above code which you wrote

Comment: @Nareshreddy Added in answer

Comment: You are a Master...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by using [sets operations](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/)

#### Data Preparation

```
s1 = StringIO("""
firstName,lastName,age,city,country
Alex,Smith,19,SF,USA
Rick,Mart,18,London,UK
""")


df1 = pd.read_csv(s1,delimiter=',')

sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(df1)


s2 = StringIO("""
firstName,lastName,age
Alex,Smith,21
""")


df2 = pd.read_csv(s2,delimiter=',')

sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(df2)

sparkDF1.show()

+---------+--------+---+------+-------+
|firstName|lastName|age|  city|country|
+---------+--------+---+------+-------+
|     Alex|   Smith| 19|    SF|    USA|
|     Rick|    Mart| 18|London|     UK|
+---------+--------+---+------+-------+

sparkDF2.show()

+---------+--------+---+
|firstName|lastName|age|
+---------+--------+---+
|     Alex|   Smith| 21|
+---------+--------+---+
```

#### Columns - Intersections & Difference

```
common = set(sparkDF1.columns) & set(sparkDF2.columns)
diff = set(sparkDF1.columns) - set(sparkDF2.columns)

print("Common - ",common)

## Common -  {'lastName', 'age', 'firstName'}

print("Difference - ",diff)

## Difference -  {'city', 'country'}
```

Additionally you can create tables/dataframes using the above variable values

Comment: I want a Output in a table format that what column name in DF1 not matching with DF2